# Image not loading in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a problem where it seems as though images don't load in IE8, but load in literally every other browser. I still can't discern why either. I've tried quite a bit and it just doesn't load. I've tried changing filetypes, sizes, etc. and nothing works.

Here's the css in the div the image is contained in:

```
.logo { position: relative; float: left; margin: 0px 0 0 20px; }
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class='logo'><img src="/template/logo.jpg" height=90px width=70px></div>
```

Comment: you can add `alt` attribute to `<img>` tag to be sure that image position is correct on the page and then main reason of image not getting loaded could be the invalid URL of the image.

Comment: What is most likely happening is every other browser intelligently fixes HTML errors (the height and width quotes), but IE doesn't so therefore it deems it as an invalid element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try change width and height attribute values:

```
<img src="/template/logo.jpg" height="90" width="70">
```

Comment: No bueno. Still nothing. I'm not sure if the src could be an issue considering the image is contained in a file called /template/header.php

EDIT: It's not the src

Comment: Actually, I think it's a two-fold issue, because it's working now.

First, I'm working in my own dev branch for the website. Second, changing the filetype seems to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="template/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" height="90" width="70">
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I ultimately found to be the problem was a two-fold issue: First, the src was relative to the main branch of the website in development, and NOT my own branch where I was developing new features, hence IE8 wouldn't render the image unless I pointed the src to my own branch's image which I just uploaded and tried to point the src to.

Second, it was possibly both the filetype and the image dimensions. If it's not the fact it's a jpg, it's the logo was originally 1000x1000px, and resizing it might have also fixed the issue.